# NSNotificationCenter for AddressBook db

Tags: iphone, addressbook, nsnotificationcenter

I want to identify the address book changes in my app using NSNotificationCenter how to use Please help me.

Comment: You had accepted my answer below for a while, and then de-accepted it again. Could you please describe more precisely what your problem is?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly what your problem is, but if you want to be notified when the address book is modified externally, you could use

```
CFErrorRef error = nil;
ABAddressBookRef contacts = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions (NULL, &error);
if (contacts != nil) {
    ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback (contacts,
                                                 addressBookChangedExternally,
                                                 (__bridge void *)(self)
                                                 );
}
```

which assumes that the object that implements this code (`self`) implements a function (not a method)

```
void addressBookChangedExternally(ABAddressBookRef abRef, CFDictionaryRef dicRef, void *context)
```